How can i get value from select2 using only javascript without jquery
I'm trying to get the value of a select2 by the change event, but I only found ways using jquery and I want only with javascript.
selectProduct.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log(selectProduct.value)
  //test
})


You added select2 js and made it work with the jQuery library. Now instead of using select2 native code you want it to do with pure javascript? Why? Any specific reason? Seems like a study assignment or learning exercise to me.

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#event-data

If I got your needs right... Then see if this will fulfill you:


MyProduct.addEventListener
(
  'change', Event =>
  {
    console.log( 'The <select> value:', Event.target.value );
  }
);
<select id="MyProduct">
  
  <option selected disabled>SELECT PRODUCT:</option>
  
  <option value="My Product #1 Option Value"> PRODUCT # 1 </option>
  <option value="My Product #2 Option Value"> PRODUCT # 2 </option>
  <option value="My Product #3 Option Value"> PRODUCT # 3 </option>
  <option value="My Product #4 Option Value"> PRODUCT # 4 </option>
  <option value="My Product #5 Option Value"> PRODUCT # 5 </option>
  
</select>



Run the snippet and change the selection box to see the effect on the console.

Add a note that the id of the select box should be unique throughout the HTML otherwise, this code will not work. Also, the code will not work if select2 is applied to multiple select elements using the class concept.
